# Why aren't event handlers working after I've changed the src of an image?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#cherub_sub1_plus').one("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).addClass("cross");
$(this).attr("src","new_image.png");
});

$('.cross').on("click",function(){
// nothing will execute here because I've changed the src
});
```

It's odd. Whenever you change the src of an image, all event handlers are removed as well.

Comment: is `#cherub_sub1_plus` a image? why the preventDefault? how does the html look like?

Comment: In your first snippet the element does not have the `cross` class yet, so there's no handler being set. If you move the setter inside the first event handler it will work, but even then it doesn't make much sense. Either `$(this).on("click" ...)` or `$(document).on("click", ".cross", ...)` would make much better options.

Comment: They are not working because you are using `one`

Comment: Read up on event delegation with `.on()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not because you changed the source, its because you dynamically add a class, and that event handler is registered at run time. Use `.on()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".cross", function(){
    // nothing will execute here because I've changed the src
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your code like this:

```
$('#cherub_sub1_plus').on("click",function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if($this.hasClass('cross')){
        // do your magic
    } else {
        $this.addClass('cross').get(0).src = 'new_image.png';
    }
});
```

This way, it will check if the class exists, and if it does then performs some magic, otherwise adds the class and changes the src of the image. It also consolidates it into a single click handler that does not require `$(document)` level click events (costly from a performance perspective).

I also chained the assignment of your `src` and used the vanilla JS method for performance reasons. Couldn't help myself.